# C# .NET sort method (filtering min and max values)

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I'm using the .net sort method for generic lists. For example:

```
MyList.Sort();
```

Is it possible to use .net to sort a list with min and max values in mind? For example, if I wanted to sort a list and simultaneously only show list items less than 'value1' but greater than 'value2'.

Something like this:

```
MyList.Sort.Where(MyList > 50 & MyList < 30);
```

Comment: What does `only show list items...` mean?  Do you want the ones outside the range removed? Do you want to create a subset? Show how?

Comment: When answering please clarify what OP is looking for, consider to [edit] the question based on your understanding. So far it is not clear what expected output is (i.e. {1,37,35,100} -> {35,37}  or {1,100} or {1,35,37,100} or {1,35,37,100} + print 35,37).

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq extensions.

```
// top of code file
using System.Linq;

// code
var filteredSortedList = MyList.Where(x => x > 30 && x < 50).OrderBy(x => x);
// filters values between 30 and 50 not inclusive
// sorts the results
```

Note that the original list MyList is not changed, instead the result is assigned to a new variable. Also the actions are deferred until you do something on the result like calling ToList or enumerating it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your example is going to yield zero results as nothing is greater than 50 and less than 30. But assuming that was just a typo, is this what you are after?

```
 List<int> s = new List<int>();
 s.Where(r => r > 50 && r < 30).OrderBy(r => r);
```

Comment: worth noting that this _expression_ does not change the original list. You want to use the _return_ value of that expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq query for that

```
MyList = MyList
  .Where(x => x > 50 && x < 30)
  .OrderBy(x => x)
  .ToList();
```

Note that `x > 50 && x < 30` will not match any item. So you probably want to write

```
MyList.Where(x => x > 30 && x < 50).OrderBy(x => x);
```

this will remove any item below 30 and greater than 50

Answer (score 1):

After you sorted the list, you can filter it using LINQ. In your case, `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` seem useful:

```
List<int> MyList = ....

// sort
MyList.Sort();

// filter:
var result = MyList.SkipWhile(i => i < 30).TakeWhile(i => i < 50).ToList();
```

---

I'm not sure (meaning I did not test), but I guess most of the times it's faster to filter first and sort afterwards, so fewer elements have to be sorted. You can use LINQ's `Where` and `OrderBy`:

```
List<int> MyList = ....
var result = MyList.Where(i => i > 30 && i < 50).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

---

Note that I assumed your condidtion was a typo, there is no number `i < 30 && i > 50`.

Comment: "I'm not sure (meaning I did not test), but I guess most of the times it's faster to filter first and sort afterwards" - you can certainly say that the expected number of comparisons will be less if you filter first. I would imagine this translates to faster in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can something like below

```
var res = MyList.Where(val => val > minVal && val < maxVal).OrderBy(num=>num).ToList();
```

You don't need to sort your list, orderby will do it for you

Comment: Why not also use `.OrderBy(@object=>@object)` to make it more confusing :) Really no good reason to use `var` as var name (even if perfectly acceptable by syntax).

Comment: @Maddy: I think Alexei was trying to make a point that having a local variable called `var` has the potential for confusion. I have to admit I assumed it would be illegal but apparently not.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the explanation you could use any variable name. I'm used to using var variable name most of the time my bad

Comment: @Maddy: No problem. Sometimes the more oblique ways of critiquing answers can be a little hard to understand if you don't already see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This version should work on most version of .net platform.

```
    System.Collections.Generic.List<int> items = new List<int>();
    Predicate<int> FilterMethod = delegate (int item) { return item < 50 && item > 30; };
    items.FindAll(FilterMethod).Sort();
```

Comment: You don't need to use a ternary expression there, just return `item < 50 && item > 30`.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the suggestion.